# Vim Leader Shortcut Stops Executing After <CR>

Tags: vim

I have a file `~/.vim-clipboard` where I have other apps configured to echo the full path to a file, so let's say the contents of `~/.vim-clipboard` are:

```
/home/user/example.txt
```

In vim, I want to execute a leader shortcut such that:

1. The `~/.vim-clipboard` file is opened in a new vim tab,
2. The vim command `gf` is executed on the filename in the clipboard file, and
3. This file then opens in this vim tab

I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F8> gf
nnoremap <leader>y :tabnew ~/.vim-clipboard<CR><F8>
```

Unfortunately, the `<leader>y` mapping stops executing after the `<CR>` on that line. I've tried various things to get it to work, including using straight up `gf` instead of the `<F8>` mapping but I can't seem to get this to work and I can't seem to find anything helpful anywhere on SO or the interwebs.

I'm an intermediate vim user, so please forgive me if there's an easy solution to this in vimscript or something. Any help is appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `<F8>` map in the `<leader>y` map you need to use a recursive map. Change `nnoremap` (which means non-recursive map) to `nmap`:

```
nmap <leader>y :tabnew ~/.vim-clipboard<CR><F8>
```

Recursive maps are documented in `:help recursive_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, to avoid having your .vim-clipboard file in your list of buffers you could also try:

```
nnoremap <leader>y :execute 'tabnew ' . system('cat ~/vim-clipboard')
```